# Stock Market Data Analysis using Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, stock, stockquotes

I am creating a project to analyze stock data using Hadoop for my college project.  I have created the cluster on Google cloud using Cloudera manager. 
I am a complete beginner. From what I have researched, I need to obtain an API to get the data and process it using MAPR code or any other method. 
However, I don't know how to integrate that API to import that data into the hadoop cluster.

Link to the API I'm trying to use: https://www.alphavantage.co/

A python wrapper class: https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage (I dont know the use)

Someone please help me and explain to me the basic processes involved to obtain the data. I am open to suggestions as to another API or other suggestions.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to use MapR code within a Cloudera environment, you'll likely run into some issues. Unless you meant MapReduce

Comment: Besides, Cloudera does not offer Nifi. Don't know why you tagged it. Given that the README uses Pandas, and no reference to Hadoop, that API doesn't need to connect to Hadoop. You download a file and upload it to HDFS, or Google Cloud Storage

Answer (score 0):

The github repository link clearly has everything explained. You don not need to obtain the data from anywhere. Just obtain the api key from your first link and follow the github readme document. You just need to enter the ticker of the company whose stock data you want to use.

Please refer the github link you have shared. Everything is perfectly documented there.

Comment: Thank you. I got the link to the repository and was able to create it. But Now I am having trouble authenticating it. I require details to configure the SSL context.

The authentication details require the following details
Keystore Filename:
Keystore Password:
Keystore type: (JKS/PKCS12)
Truststore Filename:
Truststore password:
Truststore type: (JKS/PKCS12)

I am unable to find any such information in the site certificate. Kindly help

Comment: Before going any further, please make sure you do not have firewall issues. If you are using your college/company internet, there might me firewall constraints. 

If you are using your home internet connection and still face the same issue, you can raise a query on the " Issues " section of the above repository. Here is the link: [Issues section](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/issues)